# How to fill date gaps using calendar table

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I tried to use calendar table but my query still shows date gaps in my records, does my inner join is wrong? Here is my mysql query:

```
SELECT c.dt,a.TimeIn,a.LunchOut,a.LunchIn,a.TimeOut FROM cal c 
RIGHT JOIN attendance a ON a.ValidDate = c.dt WHERE c.dt BETWEEN DATE('2015-01-01') 
AND DATE('2015-01-30') AND a.EmpID = '01409159'
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be a left join?

Comment: and where is INNER JOIN in your query?

Comment: I tried left join but same result.

Comment: is there something wrong in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RIGHT JOIN keeps every row in your `attendance` table but drops nonmatching roles in your `cal` table.

You want a LEFT JOIN, so you can keep every row in the `cal` table.  Also, your `a.col = value` WHERE clause converts your LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN. Try moving your selectivity on `a.EmpID` from the WHERE clause to the ON clause.

Also, you should handle your date range with `>=` and `<` rather than BETWEEN, because `BETWEEN` sometimes messes up the ends of date ranges.

```
SELECT c.dt, 
       a.TimeIn, a.LunchOut, a.LunchIn, a.TimeOut
  FROM cal c 
  LEFT JOIN attendance a ON a.ValidDate = c.dt AND a.EmpID = '01409159'
 WHERE c.dt >= '2015-01-01'
   AND c.dt <  '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Comment: I missed something in your query. Please check my edit.